# Definition of a one-sided test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology

In Larry Wasserman's book "All of statistics" on p.151 there is the definition of a one-sided test:

> A test of the form
> $H_0: \theta \le \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta \gt \theta_0$
> or
> $H_0: \theta \ge \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta \lt \theta_0$
> is called a one-sided test

And in the probability course [website](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter8/8_4_3_hypothesis_testing_for_mean.php) there is exactly the same definition.

So this definition looks quite popular and widespread. I want to know how to properly name tests in which only one hypothesis is one-sided? For example, can we call the following tests one-sided (I think the first two of them are widespread enough):

$H_0: \theta = \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta \gt \theta_0$
$H_0: \theta = \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta \lt \theta_0$
$H_0: \theta \lt \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta = \theta_0$
$H_0: \theta \gt \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta = \theta_0$

Comment: One-sided tests cannot test for equality of the parameter, as you have shown in the first 2 rows.  In the second two rows, the alternative hypothesis is equality of the parameters, which is not correct.  The null hypothesis is where equality would be present.

Comment: The description of "sidedness" generally relates to the alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta \gt \theta_0$ is OK, but some authors might write
$H_0: \theta \le \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta \gt \theta_0.$

$H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta \lt \theta_0$ is OK, but
some authors might write
$H_0: \theta \ge \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta \lt \theta_0.$

In each instance above, a test of $H_0$ would use $\theta = \theta_0$ to get the null distribution, used to compute the P-value of the test.

Both of the formulations below are wrong, because $H_0$ must always contain
an $=$-sign, whether as $\theta = \theta_0,$ $\theta \le \theta_0,$ or as $\theta \ge \theta_0.$

$H_0: \theta < \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta = \theta_0.$

$H_0: \theta > \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta = \theta_0.$

Comment: +1 The problem I see with the nomenclature $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }\theta = \theta_{0}, \text{H}_{1}\text{: }\theta < \theta_{0}$ is that it leaves undefined the case where in truth $\theta > \theta_{0}$ (and vice versa for $\text{H}_{1}\text{: }\theta > \theta_{0}$). Alternative hypotheses should always express the logical complement of the null hypothesis so that together they compass the sample space of $\theta$ as in the ending clauses of BruceET's 1st and 2nd sentences.

Comment: Does this mean that test $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta \lt \theta_0$ means exactly the same as test $H_0: \theta \ge \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta \lt \theta_0$ (different authors might use different notation for $H_0$)?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Then the $\ge$ in $H_0$ may help emphasize the nature of the one-sided test, but the "$>$"-part is essentially ignored in computations for the test.

Comment: I am not sure "ignored" is the best choice of words. I prefer to think of it as [calculating the probability at the most extreme point of the null hypothesis, closest to alternative parameter space](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486799/7071).

Comment: @Alexis Alternative hypotheses *never* are the logical complement of the null hypothesis (also not in the two-sided case), because model assumptions can never be guaranteed to be true, so the complement of the $H_0$ is always *any* distribution that is not in the $H_0$, and that's a *huge* class.  In fact the alternative hypothesis specifies the *direction* of a deviation from the $H_0$ which is of interest in the specific situation. (Also a two-sided alternative specifies a direction, namely, in a standard situation, "same distributional shape, different $\theta$".)

Comment: @Lewian That is a pretty minority perspective in my experience, and again, does not address the conceptual incoherence of, for example, $\theta > \theta_{c}$ in truth when $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }\theta = \theta_{c}\text{, H}_{1}\text{:}\theta < \theta_{c}$. I agree that model assumptions are a large class, however hypothesis tests are not tests of model assumptions, but tests for parameter *values* given model assumptions, and therefore the sample space of the parameters is directly relevant to expressing a coherent null and alternative.

Comment: @Lewian (IMHO correctly) says "Alternative hypotheses never are the logical complement of the null hypothesis." In judging any doubts about this recall that important theoretical foundations of hypothesis testing trace back to the Neyman-Pearson fundamental lemma., which considers a simple (one point) hypothesis against a simple alternative. // Perhaps deliberately controversial asides work best as alternative Answers where they may be explained fully (if possible) and are subject to down-votes when warranted.

Comment: @BruceET Contemporary frequentist hypothesis testing does not comport with the NPL's orientation towards "What has more evidence: $\theta = \theta_{\text{A}}$ or $\theta = \theta_{\text{B}}$?", so gonna respectfully disagree about the null and alternative hypotheses compassing the sample space of $\theta$.

Comment: Perhaps deliberately controversial asides work best as alternative Answers where they may be explained fully (if possible), be subject to down-votes when warranted, and more likely be ignored by OP's asking basic questions.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more appropriate to write them this way.

$H_0: \theta = \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta \ne \theta_0$ (two-sided)

$H_0: \theta \le \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta > \theta_0$ (one-sided [upper-tailed])
$H_0: \theta \ge \theta_0~~$ versus $~~H_1: \theta < \theta_0$ (one-sided [lower-tailed])

Comment: How do you propose that we prove equality?

Comment: No. $H_0$ must always contain an $=$-sign to indicate the null distribution. Some authors of introductory texts get sloppy about this, so I'm not saying you couldn't have seen your formulation in print somewhere, but it is not correct.

Comment: I missed equality in the one-sided tests in my first post.  This is now corrected.  Good catch @BruceET!

Comment: Something still seems off - for the latter two, it’s possible for both the null and alternative hypotheses to be true at the same time.

Comment: Wow, I answered this way too quickly.   Thank you.

Comment: I copied the OP's code and fixed it too hastily.